# Login Keyring in Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, login

Whenever I login to my computer I get a window which says *Enter password to unlock your login keyring* and *The password that you use to login to your computer doesn't match with the login keyring*

To solve this problem I went to `Accessories`->`Password and Keys`-> right clicked on the `login` tab and found few options but that were of no use to me. Can anybody tell me why I get it and how to get rid from it?

> I have fedora 25 installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify that keyring with the utility Seahorse.

[GNOME / Keyring | ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring)